# Dividing random cloud of points in two equal groups with a single line

Tags: geometry

**A little background first:** This question arose yesterday morning as I was making chocolate chip pancakes for my kids. I decided to cut one in two and give each of my kids one half. 
However, a fight erupted because one kid accused the other of having more chocolate chip on his half.

**So my question is:** Given a cloud of points randomly distributed in a circle, is it possible to draw a line that goes through the center that would split the points evenly? If so, what is the proof?

(*Note that keeping in the "chocolate chip" spirit of the question, if a point lies directly on the line, it's considered evenly split.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not always possible. A counterexample is the three points $(\frac{1}{3},0)$, $(\frac{2}{3},0)$ and $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ in the unit circle.

Comment: Drat! Now I'll have to admit to the kids that it IS possible one got more chocolate chips than the other. :-|

Comment: If no two point chips are on a line through the origin, it can be done.